# Grouping Combination Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**$9$ buses are being sent to $3$ airports such that $3$ go to Airport $1$, $5$ go to Airport $2$, and $1$ goes to Airport $3$. Assume that the buses are sent to the airports at random.**

**$1$) In how many distinct ways can these buses be sent to the airports?**

**$2)$ If exactly one of the buses needs repair, what is the probability that it is sent to airport $2$?**

**$3$) If exactly three of the buses need repair, what is the probability that each airport receives one of the buses requiring repairs?**

For the first question, I simply though of it as a grouping combination problem so did:

$\frac{9!}{3!5!1!}=504\:\textrm{ways}$

For the second question, I thought I would assume that airport $2$ getting a broken bus was a given so did:

$\frac{8!}{3!4!1!}=280\:\textrm{ways}$

Therefore, I got the probability:

$\frac{280}{504}=\frac59\approx0.56$

So, I had a similar interpretation for the third question by assuming each airport receiving a broken bus was a given so did:

$\frac{6!}{\:2!4!0!}=15\:\textrm{ways}$

Therefore, I got the probability:

$\frac{15}{504}=\frac5{168}\approx0.03$

But I am quite unsure if my interpretation of the second and third questions was correct or not as assuming the statement as a given may not have been the correct approach.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have approached all the questions correctly, but the solution to the second question is needlessly complicated.

Imagine a scenario where you are distributing $8$ red balls and $1$ black ball among three baskets that get $3$, $5$, and $1$ ball respectively.  What is the probability that the black ball gets put into the basket that gets $5$ balls?  $\frac59$, obviously.   I would argue that it is unnecessary to calculate the number of arrangements.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That was my intuition too but my teacher told me this was a counting problem so I got worried. But yes it seems that the answers are indeed the same.

Comment: While it is important to understand methods of counting, it is also important to be able to recognize problems that have simple solutions.